# Which is faster to parse? Serialized string or plain PHP or something else?

Tags: php, performance, serialization

So, for performance reasons, I need my app to store big arrays of data in a way that's fast to parse.
I know JSON is readable but it's not fast to decode. So it's I should either convert my array into pure php code or I have to serialize it and then deserialize. So, which is faster? Are there any better solutions?
I could do a benchmark myself, but It's always better to consider other people's experiences :)

More info: By big array I mean something with about 2MB worth of data returned from calling print_r() on it!
and by converting it into pure php code I mean this:
suppose this is my array: `{"index1":"value1","index2":"val'ue2"}`
and this would what the hypothetical function convert_array_to_php() would return:

```
$array = array('index1'=>'value1' ,'index2'=>'val\'ue2');
```

Comment: Why would you convert a data array into "pure php code"? I'm not even sure that that means...

Comment: Any experience anyone has is trumped by a benchmark of your own IMHO.

Comment: @Cg Alive: Please define "big", it may be important here since it's a tradeoff question.

Comment: It's super easy to benchmark this kind of thing. Write your serialization function, and compare implementations which use serialize, var_export and json_encode.

Comment: And post your results for everyone else so we can use your experience instead of doing our own benchmarking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did a little benchmark, I put about 7MB of pure php coded array into a php file, and also put it's json version in another file and also a serialized version.
Then did a benchmark on all three of them and here is the result:
As expected, the json format was the slowest to decode, it took about 3 times longer than the pure php code to parse.
And it's interesting to know that unserialize() was the fastest one, performing around 4 times faster than the native php code.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the data and usage patterns.

Generally unserialize() is faster than json_decode(), which is faster than include(). However with large data amounts, the bottleneck is actually the disk. So `unserialize(gzdecode(file_get_contents()))` is often the fastest. The difference in decoding speed might be neglectible in comparison to reading it from disk.

If you don't really need to read out the **complete** data set for printing or calculation, then the fastest storage might be SQLite however. It often keeps indexes in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Pure php code will probably have to be the *fastest*.  However, it's unlikely to be the best option, because it is probably harder to maintain.  It depends on the nature of the data though.

Comment: interestingly and bizarrely, I have seen benchmarks that put PHP's `parse_ini_file()` above including pure PHP code. I can't find the reference right now

Comment: @Pekka: Neat!  I suppose it's possible, it's a simpler parse than parsing PHP, though PHP precompilation might affect that...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a better option available but relying on PHP solely for this to?

I am guessing that handling a few arrays of this size is going to hit your server quite hard.
Is it possible for you to maybe utilize a database with some temporary tables to do what you need to do with the data in the arrays?

Comment: Yeah, I'm worried about that too. But the way this thing works doesn't leave me with much choice. I'm thinking a combination of db and serialized strings to get the load off a bit.

Comment: Hi CG. Post up some examples of your data and we'll take a look at it?